# fwrite more than 4GB in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to setup my visual studio so that I can `fwrite` 8GB at once.

I can see `malloc` allocating 8GB by keeping track of the memory using the monitor.

However, the return value of fwrite is zero and the output file size is only 4GB.

```
size_t s = fwrite(result, sizeof(unsigned int), 0x80000000, fout);
```

I am using x64, Release mode.

Is there any other settings I should use?

Comment: Do you mean in the code you are building and debugging with VS? Or are you extending VS?

Comment: And what is the problem to implement your `_fwrite` function with 64-bit parameter calling native `fwrite` multiple times? Maybe you think that it will work slower if writes 2 blocks of 4GB?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a lot of point in using the oldest C runtime functions for working with large data, as both the Windows API and C++ have better ways of handling larger data, such as memory mapped files. For C++ memory maps files, boost has a couple of implementations.

If you really want to use fwrite, then try splitting it up, as Visual C++'s implementation of fwrite will not write large arrays in one go:

`fwrite` is implemented on top of the Windows WriteFile function, which only can write a DWORD worth of bytes, furthermore see this comment from its implementation, found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\crt\src\fwrite.c .

```
/***
*size_t fwrite(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t count, FILE *stream) -
*       write to the specified stream from the specified buffer.
*
*Purpose:
*       Write 'count' items of size 'size' to the specified stream from
*       the specified buffer. Return when 'count' items have been written
*       or no more items can be written to the stream.
*
*Entry:
*       buffer  - pointer to user's buffer
*       size    - size of the item to write
*       count   - number of items to write
*       stream  - stream to write to
*
*Exit:
*       Returns the number of (whole) items that were written to the stream.
*       This may be less than 'count' if an error or eof occurred. In this
*       case, ferror() or feof() should be used to distinguish between the
*       two conditions.
*
*Notes:
*       fwrite will attempt to buffer the stream (side effect of the _flsbuf
*       call) if necessary.
*
*       No more than 0xFFFE bytes may be written out at a time by a call to
*       write(). Further, write() does not handle huge buffers. Therefore,
*       in large data models, the write request is broken down into chunks
*       that do not violate these considerations. Each of these chunks is
*       processed much like an fwrite() call in a small data model (by a
*       call to _nfwrite()).
*...
```

Note the section beginning **No more than 0xFFFE bytes may be written out at a time by a call to write()** - apart from simplicity, there isn't an advantage calling it with a large chunk of memory vs making several calls with smaller chunks and checking the return.

Comment: I don't read that as a limit on how large a request can be sent to `fwrite()`, I read that as implementation details stating that such a large request will be "broken down into chunks".

Comment: Besides, `FFFE` is a `WORD`, not a `DWORD`. You're reading comments from the Win16 era. Win32 doesn't have "near arrays".

Comment: @MSalters it's not my fault that Microsoft haven't updated their comments for a while!

Comment: @AndrewHenle The intention was to point at that fwrite is not the API to use with a single 8gb array, clarified that a bit at the top.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the first paragraph.  `fwrite` is part of the C run-time library, so I'm not sure what this has to do with Posix libraries.  The Windows API has facilities for memory mapped files, but C++ does not.  And it's not clear memory mapped files are any better at large data if your just going to write or read large chunks sequentially.  The rest of this answer looks fine.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I probably was thinking of NT's implementation of many Posix functions which don't do anything but return zero. The mapped file operations should either work or fail, rather than writing part of the file - if you request a 8gb file to be created you either get an 8gb file or do not, you don't get a file which won't grow past 4gb.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you're getting a zero return value.  Per [the MS documentation for `fwrite()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9t88zwz.aspx):

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> size_t fwrite(  
>    const void *buffer,  
>    size_t size,  
>    size_t count,  
>    FILE *stream   
> );
> ```

you've written more than zero items in order to get a 4 GB output file. Exactly how do you know the return value is zero?

Second, there's no point in trying to write such a huge amount in one line of code - partial writes are always possible, where a write attempt of any size can result in less than that amount being written.  And when you write gigabytes at a time, partial writes are going to be very likely, so you have to write code to handle the partial writes anyway.  Performance-wise, even on extremely high-speed disk systems you'll stop seeing performance improvements once write sizes get into the megabyte range.  On consumer-grade commodity systems, performance won't likely improve once your write requests get to a few kilobytes.

Third, if you're not adjusting the buffer size of your `FILE *` object, it's probably buffered in chunks of 4 or 8 KB anyway.  It's not a coincidence that's about the size where larger chunks don't result in much if any performance improvement on the majority of disk systems.

Finally, as @Andriy Berestovskyy stated in his answer, you might be running into a file system limitation.  See if you can write a file larger than 4GB using multiple `fwrite()` calls.

Comment: "64-bit Windows defines size_t as a 32-bit unsigned integer type". No, it doesn't. Quoting<crtdefs.h>: `#ifdef _WIN64 typedef unsigned __int64    size_t;`

Comment: "partial writes are always possible, where a write attempt of any size can result in less than that amount being written. ". True, the disk can be full, and this can be a temporary condition. In practice, with disk I/O, "disk full" is not a temporary condition.

Comment: "On consumer-grade commodity systems, performance won't likely improve once your write requests get to a few kilobytes.". For NTFS, that would be 65536 KB. The `FILE*` buffering is merely a first internal buffer before the OS, and _there_ you do have large buffers. The small internal buffer avoids OS calls for just a few bytes, it's not intended to save on physical I/O.

Comment: Apart from the size_t mistake, this is the correct answer. I'll upvote hoping that you fix that.

Comment: @2501 Working on that now.  Not sure where that came from?  Obvious in hindsight, but I know I was thinking how the OP got a zero return value and perhaps I was thinking about `long` on Windows still being 32 bits.

Comment: @MSalters Fixed that brain fart.  I believe I must have been thinking about `long` being 32-bits, and fixated on that being the reason the OP is getting a zero return value - which shouldn't be happening given the problem description.